# Validate JWT in another service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I have a client (Postman) and 2 public APIs (ImagesService and AdministrationService)

[image]

[image]

ImagesService and AdministrationService have some actions with authorization

```
[Authorize(Policy = "Administrator")]
```

UsersService is the service to verify the token recieved on the other services is valid.

When the client calls to DeleteUser action, I want the AdministrationServices calls automatically to UserService and validate the token.

UsersService.Startup.cs

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Core.Settings.Apis.User.Name,
                    ValidAudience = Core.Settings.Apis.User.Name,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Core.Settings.Apis.User.Secret)),
                    RequireSignedTokens = false
                };
            });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("Administrator", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Administrator", "Administrator"));
    });
```

UsersService.UsersController.cs

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Login(string nick, string password)
    {
        var claims = new List<System.Security.Claims.Claim> { new System.Security.Claims.Claim("Administrator", "Administrator" )};

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken
        (
            issuer: Core.Settings.Apis.User.Name,
            audience: Core.Settings.Apis.User.Name,
            claims: claims,
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)
        );

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

        return Ok(tokenHandler);
    }
```

AdministrationService.ManageUsersController.cs

```
 [HttpDelete]
 [Authorize(Policy = "Administrator")]
 public IActionResult DeleteUser(UserViewModel user)
 {
     // ...
 }
```

Comment: What's the question now? You just wrote what you want, but not where the problem is or which question you have.

Comment: How to comunicate the AdministratorService with the UsersService to validate the token. Do i need to add the claims on all Services?

Comment: Does your user service has introspection endpoints?

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius No

Comment: Then you can't validate the token, why do you need to validate the token? It should already have all the claims. In fact, I would recommend against creating your own token service in general.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius I need to because I have microservices

Comment: You don't need to, you made a design decision to implement your own token service. More often than not, such decision will be wrong because you won't have the expertise or the resource. Have you considered existing open source token services? Like IdentityServer? Don't have to take me for granted but even MSDN recommends not to implement your own token service (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/web-api)